# VSCode does not find virtual environment anymore

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

Lately, VSCode has been unable to find the virtual environment present in my project folder.

Suprisingly, the PYTHONPATH is set correcty:

```
"python.pythonPath": "$(workspaceFolder)/venv/bin/python"
```

and the venvPath is also set to point to it:

```
"python.venvPath": "$(workspaceFolder)/venv"
```

What did I miss to get VSCode to propose my virtual environment as python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual environment is in your project under the `venv` directory, then I would change the setting to:

```
"python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python"
```

You should also delete the `"python.venvPath"` setting as that isn't actually a correct use of the setting (it's for [pointing to a directory that contains multiple virtual environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-settings)).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me, it turned out that I had two versions of Python installed.
This happened because I installed python first, then installed vscode, which then prompted me to install python from windows store.

The solution was to open the command palette, and change the default interpreter.

See more in the thread below:

[How do I help Python find Jupyter command 'jupyter-nbconvert', to export Jupyter Notebook to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72324781/17936316)