# How do I help Python find Jupyter command 'jupyter-nbconvert', to export Jupyter Notebook to HTML?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, sys.path

**UPDATE - A solution was found, see comments, and the end of this post for further details**

I am using Jupyter Notebook in VS Code, and trying to export my notebook to HTML through the
[Notebook menu tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvUFl.png)

In other words, I am following the instructions from [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_export-your-jupyter-notebook)

I am getting this error (in the end of "Output"), when trying to export a Jupyter Notebook to HTML or PDF:

```
Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found.

    at a.executeCommand (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1000940)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async a.export (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1007072)
    at async _.exportToFormat (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1015303)
    at async _.performNbConvertExport (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1014517)
    at async _.performExport (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1014153)
    at async _.exportImpl (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1013602)
    at async _.export (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:1013335)
    at async b.export (c:\Users\EJJ\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\out\extension.node.js:2:62972)
    at async o._executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\EJJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:83:31325)]
```

My sys.path is:

```
['c:\\Users\\EJJ\\Documents\\Python', 
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python310.zip', 
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0', 
'', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\Scripts', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo', 
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\nbconvert', 
'c:\\Users\\EJJ\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.4.1021342353\\pythonFiles\\vscode_datascience_helpers\\getVariableInfo',
'C:\\Users\\EJJ\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\nbconvert\\exporters']
```

and the nbconvert package I think is installed at:

```
C:\Users\EJJ\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\nbconvert
```

, which I find to be third from the bottom in my sys.path.

My issue seems somewhat similar to this issue:
[VScode fails to export Jupyter notebook to HTML - 'jupyter-nbconvert` not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70552618/vscode-fails-to-export-jupyter-notebook-to-html-jupyter-nbconvert-not-found)

Because of the similarity to the issue, I have tried to follow the suggestions given in that thread. I found that exporting by running the following command:

```
python -m jupyter nbconvert --to HTML Unitled-1.ipynb
```

did also not work for my installation. Instead of getting an HTML file, I got some options listed, and the error message

```
Jupyter command 'jupyter-nbconvert' not found
```

I also tried the following steps:

- Uninstalling nbconvert, and reinstalling using PowerShell as administrator
- Uninstalling Jupyter, and reinstalling using PowerShell as administrator
- Running the following command:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\EJJ\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts"
```

To try and give some more information about my installation, I ran the command `python -m jupyter --version`. This produced:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.3.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.1
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.6.3
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.11
qtconsole        : 5.3.0
traitlets        : 5.2.1.post0
```

In the end, I just wanted to gather some posts which describes the same issue, since I suspect them to not be resolved. Hopefully, any learnings from this issue might help resolve those:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4347

[VScode fails to export Jupyter notebook to HTML - 'jupyter-nbconvert` not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70552618/vscode-fails-to-export-jupyter-notebook-to-html-jupyter-nbconvert-not-found)

[VSCode fails to export jupyter notebook to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64535664/vscode-fails-to-export-jupyter-notebook-to-html)

[Unable to convert Jupyter Notebooks into python scripts Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892483/not-able-to-convert-jupiter-notebooks-into-python-scripts-jupyter-command-jupyt)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10096 (The solution is here, see comments)

**Solution**

In VScode, press CTRL+Shift+P (default setting) to open "Command Palette" (also found under "View"-tab)

Write `Jupyter : Select interpreter to start Jupyter server` in the field

Choose the other version of python (Windows Store in my case - see [image: this picture])

Try to export again, and say yes to installing Jupyter again if VSCode asks to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using this command:

`Jupyter : Select interpreter to start Jupyter server` and pick the python environment where you have nbconvert installed.

Alternatively you could install nbconvert into the environment we're using to run your notebook. It should be this one:

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Comment: Perfect - I saw that this was the solution given on GitHub by Rich Chiodo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10096. It works (almost, now I have an issue with user rights, because I'm on a company pc, but that's another post, if I don't manage to solve it). Thanks for posting the issue on GitHub, I had not thought of it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **export** tool in vscode to convert it to pdf.
[image]

For more info go to this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#:%7E:text=you%20can%20export%20a%20jupyter%20notebook%20as%20a%20python%20file%20(.py)%2C%20a%20pdf%2C%20or%20an%20html%20file.%20to%20export%2C%20select%20the%20export%20action%20on%20the%20main%20toolbar.%20you%27ll%20then%20be%20presented%20with%20a%20dropdown%20of%20file%20format%20options.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have edited my question to clarify my issue

Comment: It gives the exact same error